# espresso testing : swipe operation doesnt fire the right touch event sequence Android

Tags: android, touch-event, android-espresso

I am writing an app to mimic the sticky header feature, when listview is scrolled up, the header will be hidden and nav. bar will stick to top. I implemented a custom listview and override dispatchTouchEvent onIntercepteTouchEvent, and also onScrollListener. So the code of my listview is :

```
public class MyListView extends ListView {
private ObservableScrollViewCallbacks mCallbacks;
private boolean mIsFlingEnded = true;
private OnScrollListener mScrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        mIsFlingEnded = scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onScrollChanged(mScrollY, mOnDragging, mIsFlingEnded);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        onScrollChanged();   // calculate scrolled offset
    }
};

public StickyHeaderObservableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    this.setOnScrollListener(mScrollListener);
    mListViewItemHeights = new SparseIntArray();
}

public interface ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {
    public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean dragging, boolean isFlingEnded);

    public void onDownMotionEvent();

    public void onMoveEnded(boolean isFlingEnded);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int actions = event.getAction();
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        if (actions == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || actions == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            mOnDragging = false;
            mCallbacks.onMoveEnded(mIsFlingEnded);
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        final float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mCallbacks.onDownMotionEvent();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mOnDragging = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mOnDragging = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Right now I am writing a test on listview to swipe up. The swipeUp method is implemented just like swipeLeft or swipeRight of espresso source code : [swipeLeft()](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/espresso/lib/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/action/ViewActions.java#74)

Code for swipeUp

```
public static ViewAction swipeUp() {
    return new GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.FAST, GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER, Press.FINGER); }
```

This method works fine, by "fine" I mean that the listview can scroll up, but the headers positions don't change. The reason is that the dispatchTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent are called after onScrollChanged(). This is not right. 
So when I scroll the listview using my finger, it works great, the right sequence touch event is: dispatchTouchEvent() -> onInterceptTouchEvent() -> onScrollChanged() -> onScrollStateChanged().

My first thought is that this swipeUp method might not be right, do we have alternatives of using this swipeUp?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Found the solution here, i am using Espresso 2.0, and it cause listview scroll to top when using onData, atPosition().
Link here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-test-kit-discuss/LugJjkxek3E